# How to get all keys from the cache in Apache Ignite C++

Tags: c++, ignite

There is a function specified to get the values based on the keys.

```
std::map<K, V> GetAll(const std::set<K>& keys)
```

How can I retrieve all the keys that are present in all the nodes for a cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ScanQuery`](https://www.gridgain.com/sdk/pe/latest/cppdoc/classignite_1_1cache_1_1query_1_1ScanQuery.html) for this:

```
ScanQuery qry;
QueryCursor<int, QueryPerson> cursor = cache.Query(qry);
while (cursor.HasNext())
{
    CacheEntry<int, QueryPerson> entry = cursor.GetNext();

    std::cout << entry.GetKey() << std::endl;
}
```